# OpenLayers WFS - GetFeature Draw Circle

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, getfeature

I am developing GIS Portal using OpenLayers, I use `WFS` `GetFeature` to retrieve some data like bellow:

```
var layer = map.getLayersByName("pf_trecho_at");
var polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer");
var protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(layer[0], {
                    url: "/geoserver/wfs",
                    featurePrefix: 'light',
                    readFormat: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(),
                    outputFormat: "JSON",
                    extractAttributes: true
                });
control = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({                   
            protocol: protocol,
            box: true,
            hover: true,
            multipleKey: "shiftKey",
            toggleKey: "ctrlKey"
        });

control.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e) {                  
            polygonLayer.addFeatures([e.feature]);

            this.displayPopup(e, 'pf_trecho_at');
        });
        control.events.register("featureunselected", this, function(e) {
            polygonLayer.removeFeatures([e.feature]);
        });

map.addLayer(polygonLayer);
map.addControl(control);
control.activate();
```

My doubt is, the selection control draw a rectangle to select the features, is it possible to draw a circle to select then?

Answer (score 3):

The link below contains an example using an OpenLayers2 DrawFeature control that allows to select features via a circle. It can help using WFS GetFeature to retrieve some datas using polygon or linestring drawing tools  [ows.js : Ease OGC Web Services (OWS) calls with javascript](https://github.com/frangin2003/ows.js).